# Tenho esta query e não estou a conseguir agrupar por mes

Tags: banco-de-dados, sql-server, query, ssms

```
DECLARE @Year INT = 2005, @Month INT = 7 
SELECT   --SequenceNo = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY OrderDate),
         Year = Year(convert(int,OrderDate,111)),
         case Month(convert(int,OrderDate,111)) 
        when 1 then 'Janeiro'
        when 2 then 'Fevereiro'
        when 3 then 'Março'
        when 4 then 'Abril'
        when 5 then 'Maio'
        when 6 then 'Junho'
        when 7 then 'Julho'  
        when 8 then 'Agosto'
        when 9 then 'Setembro'
        when 10 then 'Outubro'
        when 11 then 'Novembro'
        when 12 then 'Dezembro' 
        else 'unknown'
end as "Month1",
         Month = Month(convert(int,OrderDate,111)),
         TotalDue = convert(money,TotalDue,1),
         [Running Total] = convert(money,
         (SELECT sum(convert(money,TotalDue,1))
          FROM   Sales.SalesOrderHeader as Header
          WHERE  SalesOrderID <= soh.SalesOrderID
               AND year(OrderDate) = @Year
               AND month(OrderDate) = @Month),
                                         1)
FROM     Sales.SalesOrderHeader soh
WHERE    year(OrderDate) = @Year
         AND month(OrderDate) = @Month
group by Year, Month
order by 1, 2
```

Quando tento executar o group by aparece:

> Erro Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 31 Invalid column name 'Year'.
>   Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 31 Invalid column name 'Month'.

Comment: Qual é a versão do SQL Server? Há formas mais eficientes de calcular _running totals_, principalmente a partir da versão 2012.

Comment: a versão é a de 2012

Comment: Alguma das resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de escolher uma e marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Answer (score 0):

Você não colocou as colunas `year` e `month` no `SELECT`. Para usar a cláusula `GROUP BY` é preciso que as colunas que serão agregadas estejam no `SELECT`.

Comment: Eu tenho o year e o month.
Year = Year(convert(int,OrderDate,111))
Month = Month(convert(int,OrderDate,111))

Comment: Você precisa explicitar as colunas `month` e `year` na consulta para usar o `GROUP BY`. Não importa que você já tenha os valores, é uma regra da instrução `SELECT`.

Comment: Tente apelide as colunas criadas,  assim:

    Year = Year(convert(int,OrderDate,111)) as Year
    Month = Month(convert(int,OrderDate,111)) as Month